# How to get the most recent record of multiple of the same records in a table while joining another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT tblSign.sigdate,tblSign.sigtime,tblSign.sigact,tblSign.esignature,tblEmpl.fname,tblEmpl.lname,tblEmpl.location, tblEmpl.estatus,tblLocs.unit,tblLocs.descript,TblLocs.addr1,tblLocs.city,tblLocs.state, tblLocs.zip
FROM tblEmpl
LEFT JOIN tblSign
   ON tblSign.eight_id = tblEmpl.eight_id
      AND tblSign.formid = '9648'
      AND tblSign.sigact <> 'O'
      AND tblSign.sigdate >= '2022-11-01'
LEFT JOIN tblLocs
    ON tblEmpl.location = tblLocs.location
WHERE tblEmpl.estatus = 'A'
    AND tblEmpl.location = '013'
ORDER BY
     tblSign.sigdate ASC;
```

My table Sign has multiple records with the same eight_id so Im just trying to join tables getting the most recent record from tblSign besides multiple records

Data I get

| Sigdate | fname | lname | location | sigact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | Bill | Lee | 023 | A |
| 2022-10-01 | Bill | Lee | 023 | A |
| 2022-11-01 | Carter | Hill | 555 | A |

This is what I want :

| Sigdate | fname | lname | location | sigact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 | Bill | Lee | 023 | A |
| 2022-11-01 | Carter | Hill | 555 | A |

Comment: we can't understand your structure without data or what result you expect from the missing data

Comment: one sec @nbk about to post

Comment: Check now  I updated @nbk

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting into better code-writing habits. Having all column names in one long string is horrible for readability and consequently troubleshooting. You can select the most recent record from a table by using a `ROW_NUMBER` function. I took your code, cleaned it up, added a derived table and in the derived table added a `ROW_NUMBER` function. I can't validate that the query works because you didn't post example source data from your tblEmpl, tblSign, and tblLocs tables. I'm not sure if the `AND tblSign.sigact <> 'O'` is valid in the derived table because it's not clear if you were trying to just limit the date range or that was your attempt to retrieve the most recent date.

```
SELECT 
    tblSign.sigdate
    , tblSign.sigtime
    , tblSign.sigact
    , tblSign.esignature
    , tblEmpl.fname
    , tblEmpl.lname
    , tblEmpl.location
    , tblEmpl.estatus,tblLocs.unit
    , tblLocs.descript
    , TblLocs.addr1
    , tblLocs.city
    , tblLocs.state
    , tblLocs.zip
FROM tblEmpl
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *

            --Used to order the records for each eight_id by the date. 
            --Most recent date for each eight_id will have row_num = 1.
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eight_id ORDER BY sigdat DESC) as row_num
        FROM tblSign as ts
        WHERE tblSign.formid = '9648'
            AND tblSign.sigact <> 'O'
            AND tblSign.sigdate >= '2022-11-01' --Not clear if this is just to limit results or an attempt to get most recent date in the failed original code.
    ) as ts
        ON ts.eight_id = tblEmpl.eight_id
        AND ts.row_num = 1  --Use to limit to most recent date.
    LEFT JOIN tblLocs
        ON tblEmpl.location = tblLocs.location
WHERE tblEmpl.estatus = 'A'
    AND tblEmpl.location = '013'
ORDER BY
    tblSign.sigdate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You use ROW_NUMBER to get the last entry in my case for every esignature, as i thought this must be unique

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 
    tblSign.sigdate,
    tblSign.sigtime,
    tblSign.sigact,
    tblSign.esignature,
    tblEmpl.fname,
    tblEmpl.lname,
    tblEmpl.location,
    tblEmpl.estatus,
    tblLocs.unit,
    tblLocs.descript,
    TblLocs.addr1,
    tblLocs.city,
    tblLocs.state,
    tblLocs.zip,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblSign.esignature ORDER BY tblSign.sigdate DESC) rn
FROM
    tblEmpl
        LEFT JOIN
    tblSign ON tblSign.eight_id = tblEmpl.eight_id
        AND tblSign.formid = '9648'
        AND tblSign.sigact <> 'O'
        AND tblSign.sigdate >= '2022-11-01'
        LEFT JOIN
    tblLocs ON tblEmpl.location = tblLocs.location
WHERE
    tblEmpl.estatus = 'A'
        AND tblEmpl.location = '013')
SELECT     sigdate,
    sigtime,
    sigact,
    esignature,
    fname,
    lname,
    location,
    estatus,
    unit,
    descript,
    addr1,
    city,
    state,
    zip
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY sigdate ASC;
```